# Find a series expression on [0, 1/2] for the solution of the integral equation

Tags: real-analysis

Find a series expression on [0, 1/2] for the solution of the Volterra integral equation $$ f(x) =  λ \int_a^x K(x,y) f(y) dy + φ(x) $$ if $ K(x,y) = x $ and $a = 1 $. 
Professor also said to put $λ = 1$ and "phi_1"$ = 1$.

It's my first rime solving integral equations, so I am struggling even with understanding what he meant by "phi_1"...

Could someone explain this to me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Let $T$ be the operator $Tf(x) = \int_a^x K(x,y) f(y)\; dy$, so the integral equation says $f = \lambda T f + \varphi$, or $(I-\lambda T) f = \phi$ where $I$ is the identity operator.
Formally, the solution is 
$$ f = (I-\lambda T)^{-1} \varphi = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \lambda^k T^k \varphi$$
Under appropriate conditions, $T$ is a bounded linear operator on some Banach space of functions containing $\varphi$, and then for $|\lambda|$ sufficiently small this series converges in the norm of that space.

Comment: With respect, given the nature of the OP's post, this may be like lighting a furnace to burn a hair.

Comment: It may be what "Professor" is leading up to.